# Evaluate $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{n^2+2n}-\left[\sqrt{n^2+2n}\right]$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Evaluate $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{n^2+2n}-\left[\sqrt{n^2+2n}\right]$$

where $[.]$ is Greatest integer function

My try:

We have $$L=\lim_{n \to \infty} \left\{\sqrt{n^2+2n} \right\}$$ where $\left\{.\right\}$ denotes Fractional part of $x$

we have $$L=\lim_{n \to \infty} \left\{n \left(\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{n}}\right)\right\}$$

Now we have $$\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{n}}\right)=1+\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{2n^2}$$

Hence

$$L=\lim_{n \to \infty} \left\{n+\frac{n}{n}-\frac{1}{2n}\right\}$$ So

$$L=\lim_{n \to \infty} 1-\frac{1}{2n}=1$$

Is this right approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$n^2<n^2+2n<n^2+2n+1$$

$$n<\sqrt{n^2+2n}<(n+1)$$

So $\lfloor \sqrt{n^2+2n}\rfloor =n$

So we have to calculate  $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\bigg(\sqrt{n^2+2n}-n\bigg)$$

Comment: Why this way is wrong : $\lfloor \sqrt{n^2+2n}\rfloor = x , \lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{n^2+2n}-\left[\sqrt{n^2+2n}\right] =  \lim_{x \to \infty} x - \lfloor x \rfloor $ so the limit doesn't exist .

Comment: @S.H.W: It seems clear from the question that $n$ ranges over the positive integers, not over the positive real numbers, and that matters in this question. Your comment assumes $n$ ranges over the positive reals.

Comment: @RoryDaulton Oh you're right . I got it , thanks .